# Revolution Slider - Load slider when on screen only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, revolution-slider

I have this site: **http://362.a07.myftpupload.com/**
The password is: **aynhoe_park**

I need to fix it so that the Revolution Sliders on each Section to only load when its scrolled onto. Can anyone suggest / give me some jQuery to force this to only start the sliders when the user is on the page with it. You will see that the site is a parallax and it has multiple sliders on the parallax.

I have tried this code below, from the people at Revolution Slider, which doesn't seem to work:

```
revapi5.on('revolution.slide.onloaded', function() {

// slider reaches top of screen
jQuery(this).waypoint(function(direction) {

    // slider scrolled into view
    if(direction === 'up') {
        jQuery(this).revresume();
    }

    // slider scolled out of view
    else {
        jQuery(this).revpause();
    }

}, {offset: function() {

    return -jQuery(this).height();

// slider reaches bottom of screen
}}).waypoint(function(direction) {

    // slider scrolled into view
    if(direction === 'down') {
        jQuery(this).revresume();
    }

    // slider scrolled out of view
    else {
        jQuery(this).revpause();
    }

}, {offset: function() {

    return jQuery(window).height();

}});
});
```

So If someone can help me out that would be great! As I would love just one bit of code not one for each slider to force it to run the slider only when it is in the screen, not before hand.

Thanks in advance.

Chris

Comment: Are you loading the jQuery Waypoints plugin?

Comment: yes its in the <head> just before the close.

Comment: First you need to establish if it's failing to trigger when scrolled into a view (a problem with Waypoints) or whether it's failing to start and stop (a problem with Revolution). Try putting in some alerts or console messages inside your waypoint functions and see if they trigger correctly.

Comment: Actually the *first* thing should checking whether the 'revolution.slide.onloaded' event is firing; throw in an alert just after that first line.

Comment: Put an alert in, which is showing all of them at the very beginning of the load function. Its as if they are ignoring all the different sections. It looks like the waypoints are working, but not recognising that they aren't on the screen, it thinks that they all are at the same time.

Comment: I removed the alert as the client was looking at the site. Ultimately I think that a different way to do it might be to only load the contents of a <section> when the section is visible within the screen. But I don't know how to achieve this. Any help would be great.

Comment: So you've confirmed that the onloaded event is firing; next is to see if the waypoint functions are working. Just after `jQuery(this).waypoint(function(direction) {` you can put `window.console.log('Waypoint function'+this);` You can then check if that appears in your console (so that it doesn't appear as an alert.) If you get a message in the console you know that waypoints is working correctly.

Comment: ok added that and I'm getting 3 references in the console for Waypoint, when there should be 5 in total. It seems to be loading twice from the same place and once from somewhere else... This is very perplexing. its as if only 2 of them are actually firing correctly.

Comment: even though it is actually in all of the sliders (they all have their own custom js field). I do wonder if the jQuery for this should be outside of the actual slider element itself, in a js file or something like that.

Comment: looking at it again, they now are calling properly, but from the console it looks like the jQuery is only firing when you scroll past the specific slider.. which is odd.

Answer (score 1):

The code is so far correct. Please make sure that you change the "revapi5" against to the correct references.

If i check your site, i see revapi1, revapi2, revapi25, revapi26, revapi3, revapi4, ...28, ...29.  No revapi5 which would exactly declare why this not working for you. Changing your example above from revapi5 to revapi1 i.e. would start/stop the First slider on the page dependent on the scroll position.

In case you wish to drive all your sliders in the page, you will need to add for each one an individual script based on the example above, or a script which takes care of all sliders in one go like this:

```
jQuery('.rev_slider').each(function() {  

jQuery(this).waypoint(function(direction) {

    // slider scrolled into view
    if(direction === 'up') {
        jQuery(this).revresume();
    }

    // slider scolled out of view
    else {
        jQuery(this).revpause();
    }

}, {offset: function() {

    return -jQuery(this).height();

// slider reaches bottom of screen
}}).waypoint(function(direction) {

    // slider scrolled into view
    if(direction === 'down') {
        jQuery(this).revresume();
    }

    // slider scrolled out of view
    else {
        jQuery(this).revpause();
    }

}, {offset: function() {

    return jQuery(window).height();

}});
});
```

hope this helps you further ?